# How to send data pipo in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

my code is written for receiving 4 bits of data packing them to 32 bits and sending them to arm processor when the trigger is 1 (after 9 clock cycles)

The problem is

1. Data is only stored on my final register l1 at the first clock
   cycle
2. I get a warning from ise that my 2 registers sr1 and sr2
   are not connected to my too module (or1) and they get omitted from
   synthesis

I will be very thankful if you guys help me with this.

Here is my code

### -----------------------------------------------------------

```
-- Create Date:    18:54:09 12/11/2018 
-- Design Name: GPS module
-- Module :    final1 - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
entity counter is
port(clk : in std_logic;
digit : out integer range 0 to 16);
end counter;

architecture counter of counter is
begin

count: process (clk)
variable temp : integer range 0 to 17;
begin
if (clk'event and clk='1') then 
temp :=temp+1;
if (temp=17) then temp:=0;
end if; 
end if;
digit <= temp;
end process count;
end counter;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity test221 is

Port (clk1, rst : in std_logic ; datain : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       dataout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));

end test221;

architecture Behavioral of test221 is

 signal x : integer range 0 to 16;
 component counter
 port(clk : in std_logic;
digit : out integer range 0 to 16);
end component;
begin
digit1 : counter port map(clk=> clk1,  digit => x );

sr1: process (clk1,rst)
variable n : integer :=0;
begin
n := 0;
if (rst='1') then
dataout <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
elsif (clk1'event and clk1='1')then
if (x <8) then
if (n>28) then dataout <= "00000000000000000000000000000000" ; n := 0;
end if;
if (x=0 and n=0) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=1 and n=4) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=2 and n=8) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=3 and n=12) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=4 and n=16) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=5 and n=20) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=6 and n=24) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n:=n+4;

elsif (x=7 and n=28) then 
dataout(31-n) <= datain(0);
dataout(31-(n+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout(31-(n+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout(31-(n+3)) <= datain(3);
n := n + 1;

end if;
end if;
end if;
end process sr1;
end Behavioral;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity test222 is
Port (clk2,rst2: in std_logic; datain : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       dataout2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));

end test222;

architecture Behavioral of test222 is
 signal y : integer range 0 to 16;
 component counter
 port(clk : in std_logic;
digit : out integer range 0 to 16);
end component;

begin
digit2 : counter port map (clk=>clk12 , digit => y);
sr2: process (clk2 , rst2)
variable m  : integer :=0; 
begin
m :=0;
if (rst2='1') then
dataout2 <="00000000000000000000000000000000";
elsif (clk2'event and clk2='1')then
if (y<16 and y>7) then
if (m >28) then dataout2 <= "00000000000000000000000000000000" ; m :=0;
end if;
if (y=8 and m=0) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;
elsif (y=9 and m=4) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=10 and m=8) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=11 and m=12) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=12 and m=16) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=13 and m=20) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=14 and m=24) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m:= m+4;

elsif (y=15 and m=28) then 
dataout2(31-m) <= datain(0);
dataout2(31-(m+1)) <= datain(1);
dataout2(31-(m+2)) <= datain(2);
dataout2(31-(m+3)) <= datain(3);
m := m + 1;

end if;
end if;
end if;
end process sr2;
end Behavioral;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
entity or1 is 
port (clk3,rst3:std_logic; tempd1 : in std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
odata1 : out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);trig :out std_logic);
end or1;
architecture behavioral of or1 is
signal l1 : std_logic vector (32 downto 0);
signal l2 : std_logic vector (32 downto 0);
signal digitm : integer range 0 to 16 ;
component test221
 Port (clk1, rst : in std_logic ; datain : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       dataout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;
component test222
Port (clk2,rst2: in std_logic; datain : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       dataout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
          end component;
component counter
 port( clk : in std_logic;
digit : out integer range 0 to 16);
end component;
begin
digit3 : counter port map (clk=>clk3 , digit => digitm);
sr1 :test221 port map ( dataout => l1);
sr2 : test222 port map (dataout2 => l2); 
r : process (clk3,rst3)
begin 
If (digitm=8)
Then tirg=‘1’;
Elsif (digitm=16)
Then
trig=‘1’;
Else trig=‘0’;

if (clk3'event and clk3='1' and rst3='0')
then 
if (digitm=7)
then
odata1 <= l1;
elsif (digitm=15)
then
odata1 <= l2;
End if;
end if;
end if;
end process r;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: Please indent your code, so we can understand it. You can assign 4 bits at a time by using slices, e.g.: `dataout(31 downto 28) <= datain(3 downto 0);`. It makes no sence to have two correlated counters `x` and `n` where `n` is 4 times `x`. Use `x * 4`. It doesn't create logic, because multiplying by factors of two is for free in a binary world. Don't assign strings of 0s to assign zero to a signal. Use the aggregate `(others => '0')`, so the tool will fill up all needed bit positions with a `0` for you. Don't use asynchronous resets! Don't use `clk'event and clk='1'`. Use `rising_edge(clk)`.

Comment: Remove dead comments created by Xilinx tools. Don't use package `std_logic_arith`!